# Rename downloaded attachment with date received

Tags: vba, outlook, runtime-error, email-attachments

Every day I receive a report (spreadsheet format) of orders submitted the prior day.

I never bothered with saving on a daily basis and now I've been tasked to perform an analysis on it.

I'm trying to run a macro to download the reports (by selecting the emails) from my archives (specific folder) and save them in a location.

The report has the same name on each email.

I don't want to save it as incremental (i.e. Service Orders - 1, Service Orders - 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.).  I would like to save it based on the date received.

When I run the code, I get an error,

> "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

for the line `dMsg = objMsg.SentOn`.

```
Sub DownloadAttachments()
Dim individualItem As Object
Dim att As Attachment
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strExt As String
Dim dicFileNames As Object
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim dMsg As Date
Dim strDate As String

strPath = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Test2\"

Set dicFileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each individualItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If TypeName(individualItem) = "MailItem" Then
        For Each att In individualItem.Attachments

            dMsg = objMsg.SentOn

            strDate = Format(dMsg, "yyyy-mm-dd")

            If Not dicFileNames.exists(att.FileName) Then
                dicFileNames.Add att.FileName, 1
            Else
                dicFileNames(att.FileName) = dicFileNames(att.FileName) + 1
            End If

            strFileName = Split(att.FileName, ".")(0)
            strExt = Split(att.FileName, ".")(1)

            att.SaveAsFile strPath & strFileName & strDate & "-" & dicFileNames(att.FileName) & "." & strExt

        Next att
    End If
Next individualItem

End Sub
```

Comment: And where do you set `objMsg`?

Comment: Isn't the objMsg defined in the Dim statement as the Outlook.MailItem?  As I said, I'm a newbie.

Comment: It's not - you've declared in on that `Dim` line, but now you need to set it. Try putting `Set objMsg = individualitem` after `If TypeName(individualItem) = "MailItem" Then`

Comment: Or you might just be able to say `individualitem.SentOn` and forget about `objMsg` altogether

Comment: OMG!  Thanks for making me look at it again.  I understand what I did wrong.  I changed the code to dMsg = individualItem.SentOn and it works perfectly.